How to change the color of CSS and XML tokens in Visual Studio Code settings.json file
Although Visual Studio Code’s settings.json file provides impressively fine-grained control over the appearance of the development environment, however, for the last 40 hours or so, I have been having trouble refining the layout of my XML and CSS files’ comments, strings, and identifiers. I would like to recalibrate the colors of the aforementioned properties without writing a theme file from the ground up. So far, I have been able to find the following properties, however, they are not generating the desired results. I would love to know that how can I target the various elements of a XML and CSS files, attributes like keywords, comments, strings, and keyword values, by merely relying on the settings.json file. This is what I have found so far:
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": 
    {
       "textMateRules": 
       [
          {
            "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.localname.xml",
        "settings": 
            {
           "foreground":        "#ce9079",
           "fontStyle":         "normal",
           "keywords":          "#f00",
           "numbers":           "#dfd51b",
           "keywords":          "#215c21",
           "thongs":            "#67f7e3",
           "variables":         "#22FF88",
           "comments":          "#B9B9B9"
        }
          },
       ]
    },

I want to change the color Orange to a lighter shade and change the color values of the variables and keywords, as well.
I have tried various settings discussed in multiple tutorials, but they are not producing the desired results.

Somebody provided the answer that solved my problem, however, since then, they have removed the answer. Hence, I am including the solution that has worked for me. If you are planning to bundle multiple entities together, then you can use square bracket with the "scope" field.
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.xml",
            "settings": 
            {
                "foreground": "#ce9079", 
                "fontStyle": "normal"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "comment", 
            "settings": 
            {
                "foreground": "#B9B9B9" 
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "string",
            "settings": 
            {
                "foreground": "#67f7e3" 
            }
        }
    ]
}

